# Custom vocabulary with AWS Transcribe- Japanese Language in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

While using aws transcriber, I want to create custom vocab but Not able to create custom vocabulary with Japanese words and nor able to find any sample of custom vocab phrases file.
Tried character code from the table and the direct japanese words array of strings. Neither worked.
Got the error "The vocabulary that you’re trying to create contains invalid characters or incorrectly formatted terms. See the developer guide for more information."
Here is my code

```
   response = transcribe.create_vocabulary(
    VocabularyName = 'vocab2',
     LanguageCode = 'ja-JP',
     Phrases = ["0x3005 0x3005"]
)
```

Any leads would be appreciated!

Comment: Same problem here, but I am using Chinese. Couldn't even work with the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to S3 first, forget the upload file button

AWS provides two ways to create custom vocabulary on the console, upload a file or fetch from s3. For the same file, I failed when uploading directly, but succeed when uploading to s3 first. I guess it's a bug in AWS, but we have to live with it.